# What is page fault and when does it occur?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

In an interview I was asked this question: what is a **page fault** and when does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it is so hard to find out:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault

Also the 3rd result in Google is exactly your question answered:

http://www.careerride.com/os-page-fault.aspx